# Как программно узнать ip компьютера в локальной сети?

Tags: winsock, c++, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте!

Знаю что вопрос истерт до нельзя, наверно, но в сети я так и ничего путевого не нашел(
Смог получить ip интернетный, а сетевой не знаю как получают... Помогите кодом или ссылкой.

Comment: Вообще вопрос "ip адрес компьютера" не имеет смысла, поскольку в tcp/ip адреса имеют не хосты (компьютеры), а их интерфейсы.

Comment: Опять тэги как попало? Еще раз прошу обратить внимание, что тэг "с++" и тэг "c++" - разные. При этом верен только последний (в en раскладке)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <winsock.h>

int doit(int, char **)
{
    char ac[80];
    if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() <<
                " when getting local host name." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Host name is " << ac << "." << endl;

    struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ac);
    if (phe == 0) {
        cerr << "Yow! Bad host lookup." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i) {
        struct in_addr addr;
        memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        cout << "Address " << i << ": " << inet_ntoa(addr) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return 255;
    }

    int retval = doit(argc, argv);

    WSACleanup();

    return retval;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Дожили, везде уже C# мерещится... Извините. ВОт, пожалуйста, нашел в гугле.

Comment: пишет error C2065: 'IPAddress' : undeclared identifier
...

Comment: Логично что пишет... Код выше на шарпе а не на C++

Comment: Да, извините, я ошибся языком :) Теперь то, что нужно.

Comment: Строго говоря, это IP не обязательно из локальной сети. Хотя конечно, при нормальных настройках,  это свой адрес в ней.

Вообще же, из вопроса не совсем ясно, IP какого именно компьютера в локалке хочет увидеть ТС.

Comment: Свой ip нужен...

Comment: Ну, в подавляющем большинстве случаев программа в ответе его (их) и выдаст, хотя берет из конфигурации и (возможно) dns.

Их, т.к. у компьютера м.б. несколько интерфейсов (сетевых плат) + loopback.

Вообще, более правильно читать IP приаттаченные к интерфейсам.

Comment: Кроме интерфейсов (плат) могут быть ещё субинтерфейсы (если название не перепутал по давности лет), каждый со своим адресом.

Вообще, если надо быстро, а копаться в доках "не до сук", то popen + ifconfig (в виндах -- ipconfig)

Comment: Спросил гугла. Первая ссылка на запрос "windows enumerate network interfaces" -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213629/how-to-enumerate-all-available-network-interfaces . А там отсылают к http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4004/The-quot-New-ipconfig-quot-and-the-IP-Helper-API (куча текста чёрным по англискому -- кому надо, тот пусть и читает).

Answer (score 2):

Перебираем все IPv4 интерфейсы:

```
#include <IpHlpAPI.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
...
void enumIPv4Interfaces()
{   
    ULONG sz = 0;
    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE tbl = NULL;
    DWORD ret = ::GetIpAddrTable(tbl, &sz, TRUE);

    if(NO_ERROR != ret && ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != ret)
    {
        //log error
        return;
    }

    tbl = (PMIB_IPADDRTABLE) GlobalAlloc(GHND, sz);

    if(NULL == tbl)
    {
        //log error
        return;
    }

    ret = ::GetIpAddrTable(tbl, &sz, TRUE);

    if(NO_ERROR != ret)
    {
        //log error
        GlobalFree(tbl);
        return;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i<tbl->dwNumEntries; ++i)
    {
        in_addr addr;
        addr.S_un.S_addr = tbl->table[i].dwAddr;

        char* ch = ::inet_ntoa(addr);

        if(NULL == ch)
        {
            //log error
            continue;
        }

        //в ch очередной IP адрес
    }

    GlobalFree(tbl);
}
```

Comment: @Dith, а как ее собрать в MinGW?

    undefined reference to `GetIpAddrTable@12'

Comment: @avp попробуйте добавить -liphlpapi. И регистр в 

     #include <IpHlpAPI.h>

подправьте (не под виндами чай). А то g++ не поймёт, что функция сишная

Comment: @alexlz, в точку!

С iphlpapi собралась, а регистр в для g++ в винде оказывается не важен. Так тоже собирает 

    #include <wiNdows.h>
    //#include <IpHlpAPI.h>
    #include <iphlpapi.h>
    #include <WinSock2.h>

Comment: Регистр -- это старая шутка MS. (с первых NT, чтоли). На диске имена с буквами в разном регистре различаются, а вот при открытии файла регистр букв игнорируется.

Блин, написал "различаются" -- несколько бессмысленно. Правильнее "регистр букв в именах на диске сохраняется".

А я забыл, что у Вас -- винды. У меня-то линукс, там регистр важен...

Comment: @alexlz, у меня тоже линукс. В винде просто для интересу иногда смотрю (ну, и чтобы знать о смежниках побольше). 

С регистром имени файла (по крайней мере в MinGW) получается, что `fopen()` (IMHO и другие вызовы тоже) его игнорирует. Вот:


    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ cat ulregopen.c 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int
    main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
      FILE *f = fopen(av[1]? av[1] : "ulregopen.c", "rb");
    
      return (f) ? 0 : (perror("fopen"), -1);
    }
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc ulregopen.c

Comment: @avp Смените подозреваемого. Если линукс, а программа -- a.exe, то виновного, скорее всего, зовут "Вино" (wine).

А с советом поменять регистр в имени хедера я был не прав.

Comment: (limit - обновил)

    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a aqqq1
    fopen: No such file or directory
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ echo $?
    255
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a aqQQ
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ echo $?
    0
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a aqqq
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ echo $?
    0
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ 
    
Да нет, @alexlz, это я плохо объясняю. Пример в реальной Windows-XP (просто из eshell в Emacs) и wine тут ни при чем.